# How do I make my dropdown menu links wider?

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown menu, with a 100% width, however the links in the dropdown are way too thin, I want the text of each link to be on one line. I feel like it's the '100% width', but without that the links are not directly under the main navigation link that the fall under.

```css
#main-nav a {
  color: #ce2029;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

#main-nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

#main-nav li {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#main-nav li:hover .sub-menu>li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 10px;
}

.sub-menu li {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #2b303a;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav id="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Website & Application Development</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iOS & Android Development</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SAAS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">AI & Data Science</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Databases</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: Sorry, not used SOF much, I added the css. wouldn't let me add html as it's 'too much code'. any help with that too lol?

Comment: Generally the idea is that you trim the code down to the minimum amount that reproduces the problem, there's a guide for creating good examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks, I've trimmed and added the HTML :)

Comment: I've turned your code into a snippet (You are missing a couple of closing tags) The width is due to the `100%` being relative to the parent `li`, which is quite narrow.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it. How can I fix that and get the width bigger with it still being under the link?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the desired result?

```css
#main-nav a {
  color: #ce2029;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

#main-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#main-nav li {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#main-nav li:hover .sub-menu>li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 10px;
}

#main-nav li:hover .sub-menu {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.sub-menu li {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #2b303a;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav id="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Website & Application Development</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iOS & Android Development</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SAAS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">AI & Data Science</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Databases</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: Thanks, yes and no. I added white-space:nowrap to #main-nav a. Now the alignment is correct but the sub-menu links pass outside of the sub-menu background!